# How to designed hierarchy in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services

I have sets of data and I want to design it in SSRS report that reflecting their hierarchy level.

Example Data

```
EmpID    Name        Position        ReportingtoID 
 1     JR Smith   Project Manager        NULL
 2     Clay Yu    Project Manager        NULL
 3     Joe Will     Programmer            1
 3     Joe Will     Programmer            2
```

This is what I did.

I group the data set by EmpID.
[image]

Then on advanced - recursive parent I put ReportingToID
[image]

I already designed it in ssrs report but the problem is only 1 Joe Will is reflected in ssrs since you group it by EmpId.

Look forward for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to rank the data based on position. 
Maybe you can add a ranking column in your dataset that assign a number to each position, for example:

```
;with t as(
SELECT *, CASE WHEN position = 'project manager' THEN 1
               WHEN position = 'programmer' THEN 2 
          END rank
FROM dataset)
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY rank
```

When you display this in SSRS, Project Manager should be on top.